# how to create a list of variables in a for loop with php

Tags: php, for-loop, variables

In a `txt` file (translations.txt) i have some lines of words which i bind to variables. A txt file looks like this:

```
All Articles
Main Articles
Previous Page
Next Page
// and so on...
```

To read the content of all these lines i put them in an array:

```
$translationfile = 'data/translations.txt'; 
$lines_translationfile = file($translationfile, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES); // all lines of the txt file into an array
// bind content to variables
$translation0 = $lines_translationfile[0] // All Articles
$translation1 = $lines_translationfile[1] // Main Articles
$translation2 = $lines_translationfile[2] // Previous Page
$translation3 = $lines_translationfile[3] // Next Page
// and so on till 40
```

I try to generate these variables with a for loop:

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= 40; $x++) {
    $translation.$x = $lines_translationfile[$x]; // Does not work...
}
```

What is the correct way to generate all these variables till 40 easily?

Comment: Why do you need these variables at all? Just use the array references.

Comment: The values of these variables may change. I let the user do the translation, and his/her translation phrase will be stored in the `translations.txt` file. Then i only have to change in the content of the php files, per example the words "Main Articles" with `$translation1`

Comment: That doesn't explain why you need the variables. Where you're using `$translation1` you can just as easily use `$lines_translationfile[1]`, although I'd probably use a less cumbersome name for the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using array, but if you want to use several variables use the following code.

```
for ($x=1; $x < 40; $x++) { 
    ${"translation".$x}=$lines_translationfile[$x];    
}
```